# how to re-adduser after delete it?

Tags: 12.04

I have use

```
sudo userdel alpha
```

to delete user alpha

and I want to add it back with

```
sudo useradd alpha
```

but after I `useradd` ubuntu didn't ask me about new password?

I add `/home/alpha` by root and change password for alpha,change the dir's owner to alpha

after I login it's only have a `$` nothing before it!

I used have `alpha@localhost$`!

how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the `$` login after creating the user use ...

```
 usermod -s /bin/bash $USER
```

Or when creating I myself tend to use the following ...

```
useradd -d /home/$USER -s /bin/bash -G group -m $USER
```

If you want another shell replace /bin/bash for that shell.

Comment: I try first way it's work!

Comment: glad you got it fixed @blueman010112 :) steeldrivers answer would have worked too by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you created the user account from scratch with an empty home directory, it didn't set the default Ubuntu login shell (bash) and associated configuration (including the `user@host` shell prompt, which is set in the .bashrc file).

You can change your login shell with

```
chsh -s /bin/bash alpha
```

and copy the configuration files manually e.g.

```
cp /etc/skel/{.profile,.bashrc,.bash_logout} /home/alpha/
```

Copy the files as user `alpha` not `sudo` so that they take on the ownership of the user. You will need to logout and back in for the changes to take effect.

If you had used `adduser` instead of `useradd` then the system would have done that automatically (as well as prompting for a password during the account creation).

Comment: So it's a wrong command under my situation...

Comment: Not wrong, just different - `useradd` is the basic command to create a user account, whereas `adduser` is a higher level command that does some extra stuff to make the resulting account more 'standard'.